# VS 2015 Юнит-Тесты. Время выполнения увеличилось в 20 раз

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, visual-studio-2015

Проблема с VS 2015. Со вчерашнего дня время на выполнение 350 юнит-тестов проекта на моей машине увеличилось с 2 до 40 минут. Время исполнения увеличилось для каждого теста в отдельности. При этом другие разработчики такой проблемы не испытывают. Из сего делаю вывод, что проблема конкретно в конфигурации VS на моём рабочем месте.
Кто нибудь может уже сталкивался с подобным и знает как это решается?

Comment: Слишком мало инфы, чтобы давать какие-то советы. Это в одном проекте или в каждом? Менялось ли что-то в студии и самой ОС (апдейты?), забирали свежие коммиты из TFS и что там в них прилетело? Проверяли ли, может у вас начал сдыхать винчестер или банально подходит место на диске к концу? Проверяли ли запущенные программы, может что-то в фоне выполняется?

Comment: @Sergej: Покамест ваш вопрос звучит так: «У меня код стал бежать медленнее, что именно поменялось, я не знаю, угадайте, в чём проблема». И ответ на такие вопросы всегда «А откуда нам знать? Спрофилируйте, сравните с быстрым вариантом».

Comment: Проверил на другом, проекте - та же проблема. Места на диске достаточно (> 30 ГБ). Ни каких запросов к базам данных нет. Сетевые ресурсы в тестах не задействованы. Нагрузка на процессор во время выполнения тестов 25%, использование оперативной памяти - 80%. В остальном всё работает нормально.

Comment: У меня в 2015 месяц назад в визуал студия в один прекрасный момент перестал работать отладчик (триал версия, до конца срока оставалось больше трех недель), проблема решилась авторизацией студии. У меня нет хороших слов в их адрес. Проблемы в прежних студиях есть?

Comment: Насчёт прежних студий не знаю. У меня установлена только VS 2015. Судя по протоколу позавчера пришло 2 апдейта на .NET Framework.

Comment: Кстати, (я сейчас работаю без VisalStudio не могу дать конкретную ссылку) там недавно приходило в информационном канале пришло сообщение, о об их ошибках приводящих к подвисанию пользовательского интерфейса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проанализировав код нескольких юнит тестов в отладчике, я понял, что "тормозят" обращения к методам из библиотеки Moq. Проблема решилась просто. После того как программный пакет Moq был обновлён мной на моей машине до актуальной версии, тесты стали обрабатываться ещё быстрее чем раньше - за 15 секунд.

Всем спасибо и хорошего дня.

Comment: Отметьте свой ответ как верный.